# Unable to type in textbox containing inside Iframe in MAc safari with voiceOver

Tags: safari, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

If there is text box inside iframe and user navigates to textbox using standard voice (Mac Safari desktop) over accessibility keys i.e. ctrl+option + right arrow, she is not able to type inside text box as cursor disappears. User able to type in-case navigating via tab. Although some times it start working fine and disappears again. this behavior can be observed in following sample link - https://plnkr.co/edit/0bg1fYXELVVJzyRcuUjG?p=preview

some potion of code-

```
<html>

  <head>   

  </head>

  <body>   

    <iframe title="testFrame" name="testFrame" src="test1.html">

    </iframe>
  </body>

</html>
```